# MySQL CLAUSE can become a value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I am new in mysql. What I would to do is create a new table which is a copy of the original one *table* with one more column under a specific condition. Which condition appears as a new column is the new table. I mean:

Let *table* be a sequence of given point (x,y) I want to create the table *temp* being (x,y,r) where r = x^2 + y^2<1  But what I did is

```
CREATE temp LIKE table;
ALTER TABLE temp ADD r FLOAT;

INSERT INTO temp (x,y) SELECT * FROM table WHERE x*x+y*y<1;
UPDATE temp SET r=x*x+y*y;
```

It is ok, it gives what I want, but my database is much more bigger than this simple example and here I calculate twice the radius r in two table. It is not so good about optimization.

Is there a way to pass the clause into the new column directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not create a view instead? That way `r` is calculated whenever you use the view

Comment: Views are not materialized in MySQL. So each time you access the "table" (defined by the view) the query gets executed - rather slow...

Comment: @Benvorth And having a almost completely redundant table is better?

Comment: If Performance is a concern: Yes.

Comment: Explain the performance hit over the maintenance hit? See @TomH answer. Gets my vote!

Comment: For instance imagine each user connecting to the database is concern by sphere of radius lesser than whatever. And during its session he will manipulate a lot of time his data. Better to have a temporary or a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to worry about doing the calculation twice.  There is more overhead to doing an `insert` and `update`.  So, you should do those calculations at the same time.

MySQL extends the use of the `having` clause, so this is easy:

```
CREATE temp LIKE table;
ALTER TABLE temp ADD r FLOAT;

INSERT INTO temp(x, y, r)
    SELECT x, y, x*x+y*y as r
    FROM table 
    HAVING r < 1;
```

It is quite possible that an additional table is not actually necessary, but it depends on how you are using the data.  For instance, if you have rather complicated processing and are referring to `temp` multiple times and `temp` is rather smaller than the original data, then this could be a useful optimization.

Also, materializing the calculation in a table not only saves time (when the calculation is expensive, which this isn't), but it also allows building an index on the computed value -- something you cannot otherwise do in MySQL.

Personally, my preference is for more complicated queries rather than a profusion of temporary tables.  As with many things with extremes, the best solution often lies in the middle (well, not really in the middle but temporary tables aren't all bad).

Comment: Thanks a lot! As mentioned above in my comments I used the VIEW method combine with the HAVING it works fine. Indeed I do not need of a real temporary table... I will think about this.

Answer (score 4):

You should (almost) never store calculated data in a database. It ends up creating maintenance and application nightmares when the calculated values end up out of sync with the values from which they are calculated.

At this point you're probably saying to yourself, "Well, I'll do a really good job keeping them in sync." It doesn't matter, because down the road at some point, for whatever reason, they will get out of sync.

Luckily, SQL provides a nice mechanism to handle what you want - views.

```
CREATE VIEW temp
AS
    SELECT
        x,
        y,
        x*x + y*y AS r
    FROM My_Table
    WHERE
        x*x + y*y < 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware about VIEW (I am a noob in mysql) but it seems to fit exactly to what I want and your method works fine! I just change the las statement "WHERE x*x+y*y<1" by "HAVING r <1" as mentioned below by Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
INSERT INTO temp (x,y) SELECT * FROM table WHERE x*x+y*y<1;
UPDATE temp SET r=x*x+y*y;
```

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO temp (x,y,r) 
SELECT  x, 
       y, 
       x*x+y*y AS r  
FROM table 
WHERE x*x+y*y<1;
```